# form exacttarget show text success and validate email

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I used one script to show a "thank you message" when send the form, but the "thank you message" is cancelling the "validation" of the input, also, you can send without any value on input.

> I need this validation working to check if its an valid email and if
>   is not empty. How can I fix it?

This is my form code:

```
<div id="btnsucess"><p>Obrigado!</p></div>
<div id="formhide">
                <form action="https://ws.inversapub.com/subscribe" data-validate="https://lp.inversapub.com/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" target="hiddenFrame">
                  <input name="emailAddress" type="email" required="" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Preencha um endereço de e-mail válido.')" placeholder="Coloque aqui seu e-mail" class="input-email" />
                   <input type="submit" value="QUERO ME INSCREVER" class="btn-submit" id="btnclick"/>
                  <input name="sourceId" type="hidden" value="XV-MEL-WV-FRI-X-X-LP-X-X" />
                  <input name="listCode" type="hidden" value="inv_hotlist_fri" />
                  <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="https://lp.inversapub.com/profit-hunter-concluido/" />
                  <input name="email_page" type="hidden" value="inv_welcome_fri" />
                </form>
<iframe name="hiddenFrame" width="0" height="0" border="0" style="display: none;"></iframe></div>
```

The script:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("btnclick").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('formhide').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('btnsucess').style.display = "block";
    };

    </script>
```

The text message is cancelling the script:

```
oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Preencha um endereço de e-mail válido.')"
```

Comment: Could you post your email validation function?

Comment: Yep, already done! Sry.